# Transposing partial data in SAS

Tags: sas, db2, sas-macro

I have a data set 'Sample' of this structure. I am querying this data table from DB2 SQL and then imported them in SAS.

```
| desc_cd | item_cd | abc | line_nbr | type_cd | val1 | val2 | val 3|
|---------|---------|-----|----------|---------|------|------|------|
|   100   |   458   | 15  |     1    |    3    |  50  |  0   |  100 |
|---------|---------|-----|----------|---------|------|------|------|
|   100   |   458   | 15  |     2    |    6    |  0   |  150 |  0   |
|---------|---------|-----|----------|---------|------|------|------|
|   100   |   458   | 15  |     3    |    9    |  50  |  150 |  0   |
|---------|---------|-----|----------|---------|------|------|------|
|   225   |   778   | 41  |     1    |    3    |  50  |  0   |  100 |
|---------|---------|-----|----------|---------|------|------|------|
|   225   |   778   | 41  |     2    |    6    |  0   |  150 |  0   |
|---------|---------|-----|----------|---------|------|------|------|
|   225   |   778   | 41  |     4    |    12   |  0   | 1990 |  230 |
|---------|---------|-----|----------|---------|------|------|------|
|   225   |   778   | 41  |     3    |    9    |  50  |  150 |  0   |
|---------|---------|-----|----------|---------|------|------|------|
```

I want to transpose the data to look like this

```
| desc_cd | item_cd | abc | line_nbr | type_cd | val1 | val2 | val3 | line_nbr_2 | type_cd_2 | val1_2 | val2_2 | val3_2 | line_nbr_3 | type_cd_3 | val1_3 | val2_3 | val3_3 | line_nbr_4 | type_cd_4 | val1_4 | val2_4 | val3_4 | 
|---------|---------|-----|----------|---------|------|------|------|------------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|------------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|------------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
|   100   |   458   | 15  |     1    |    3    |  50  |  0   |  100 |       2    |      6    |    0   |  150   |    0   |     3      |    9      |  50    |  150   |  0     |            |           |        |        |        |
|---------|---------|-----|----------|---------|------|------|------|------------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|------------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|------------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
|   225   |   778   | 41  |     1    |    3    |  50  |  0   |  100 |       2    |      6    |    0   |  150   |    0   |     4      |    12     |  0     |  1990  |  230   |     3      |    9      |  50    |  150   |  0     |
|---------|---------|-----|----------|---------|------|------|------|------------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|------------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|------------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
```

I have the following code in SAS

```
proc transpose data= sample
out= sample_merged;
var desc_cd;
var item_cd;
var abc; 
by line_nbr;
by type_cd;
by val1;
by val2;
by val3;
run;
```

However, this doesn't work and doesn't give the desired output. Anyway I can do this in SAS or PROC SQL (DB2 SQL)? The line_nbr and type_cd could be even more than 4 and 12 respectively. Hence I don't want to hardcode the values.

Comment: Why? This format will be harder to work in. You need to transpose each variable on it's own and then merge the results together. Or use an array but this assumes you know the maximum number of items you can possibly have.

Comment: Array + Data step method: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/modules/reshaping-data-long-to-wide-using-the-data-step/

Comment: Multiple Transpose method: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/modules/how-to-reshape-data-long-to-wide-using-proc-transpose/

Comment: Recent macro versions: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Transpose-your-analysis-data-with-the-MAKELONG-and-MAKEWIDE/ta-p/791732

Comment: @Reeza..true, but the original data would have very large number of rows in the given format. That data would be joined with more data and that would be even higher number of rows.

Comment: More rows are easier to deal with than more columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a report use PROC REPORT.

Let's convert your listing into actual data.

```
data have;
input desc_cd item_cd abc line_nbr type_cd val1-val3;
cards;
100 458 15 1  3 50    0 100 
100 458 15 2  6  0  150   0 
100 458 15 3  9 50  150   0 
225 778 41 1  3 50    0 100 
225 778 41 2  6  0  150   0 
225 778 41 4 12  0 1990 230 
225 778 41 3  9 50  150   0 
;
```

Now you can use LINE_NBR as an across variable to make report like you wanted.

```
proc report data=have;
  column desc_cd item_cd abc (type_cd val1-val3),line_nbr;
  define desc_cd / group;
  define item_cd / group;
  define abd / group;
  define line_nbr / across ' ';
run;
```

[image]

If you actually want to make that dataset and you want to use LINE_NBR as the SUFFIX on the new variable names then just use TWO transpose steps.  One to convert your current WIDE format into a normalized TALL format.  Then a second one to convert the TALL format to your desired REALLY WIDE format.

```
proc transpose data=have out=step1;
  by desc_cd item_cd abc line_nbr NOTSORTED ;
  var type_cd val1-val3;
run;

proc sort data=step1;
  by desc_cd item_cd abc _name_ line_nbr ;
run;

proc transpose data=step1 out=want(drop=_name_) delim=_;
  by desc_cd item_cd abc ;
  id _name_ line_nbr ;
  var col1;
run;
```

If you don't want to use LINE_NBR as the suffix on the new variable names (or if you have mixed numeric and character variables you want to transpose) then use PROC SUMMARY to do the transpose.  The variables will be numbered by their order (as opposed to the earlier methods that use the value LINE_NBR to name the variables) so sort order makes a difference.  Notice that your example data has LINE_NBR 4 before LINE_NBR 3 for the second group.

```
proc summary data=have ;
  by desc_cd item_cd abc  ;
  output out=want(drop=_freq_ _type_) idgroup(out[3] (line_nbr type_cd val1-val3)=);
run;
```

Also PROC SUMMARY requires you to set the upper bound on how many copies of the variables you want to make.  If you don't know then you could ask SAS to count for you and put the count into a macro variable that you can use in the PROC SUMMARY step.

```
proc sql noprint;
select max(count) into :max trimmed
  from (select desc_cd,item_cd,abc,count(*) as count from have group by 1,2,3)
;
quit;
proc summary data=have ;
  by desc_cd item_cd abc  ;
  output out=want(drop=_freq_ _type_) idgroup(out[&max] (line_nbr type_cd val1-val3)=);
run;
```

Comment: This assumes all variables are the same type, if they're different there will be a conversion I assume?

Comment: Yes.  If there are mixed type then they all become character strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
%let pgm=utl-transpose-pivot-skinny-to-fat-multiple-sets-of-variables-in-wps-and-sas;

Transpose pivot skinny to fat multiple sets of variables in wps and sas

For complete post see (have list of related repositories)

github

https://github.com/rogerjdeangelis/utl-transpose-pivot-skinny-to-fat-multiple-sets-of-variables-in-wps-and-sas

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76393224/transposing-partial-data-in-sas

Solutions

    1 WPS (one line of code)
      utl_transpose( data=sd1.have,by=desc_cd item_cd,var=abc line_nbr type_cd val1-val3,out=want)

    2 SAS (one line of code)
      utl_transpose( data=sd1.have,by=desc_cd item_cd,var=abc line_nbr type_cd val1-val3,out=want)

Related Transpose Repositories on github see

/*                   _
(_)_ __  _ __  _   _| |_
| | `_ \| `_ \| | | | __|
| | | | | |_) | |_| | |_
|_|_| |_| .__/ \__,_|\__|
        |_|
*/

libname sd1 "d:/sd1";
data sd1.have;
   input desc_cd item_cd abc line_nbr type_cd val1-val3;
cards4;
100 458 15 1  3 50    0 100
100 458 15 2  6  0  150   0
100 458 15 3  9 50  150   0
225 778 41 1  3 50    0 100
225 778 41 2  6  0  150   0
225 778 41 4 12  0 1990 230
225 778 41 3  9 50  150   0
;;;;
run;quit;

/**************************************************************************************************************************/
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* Up to 40 obs from last table SD1.HAVE total obs=7 17MAY2023:09:28:09                                                   */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* Obs    DESC_CD    ITEM_CD    ABC    LINE_NBR    TYPE_CD    VAL1    VAL2    VAL3                                        */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/*  1       100        458       15        1           3       50        0     100                                        */
/*  2       100        458       15        2           6        0      150       0                                        */
/*  3       100        458       15        3           9       50      150       0                                        */
/*  4       225        778       41        1           3       50        0     100                                        */
/*  5       225        778       41        2           6        0      150       0                                        */
/*  6       225        778       41        4          12        0     1990     230                                        */
/*  7       225        778       41        3           9       50      150       0                                        */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/**************************************************************************************************************************/
/*           _               _
  ___  _   _| |_ _ __  _   _| |_
 / _ \| | | | __| `_ \| | | | __|
| (_) | |_| | |_| |_) | |_| | |_
 \___/ \__,_|\__| .__/ \__,_|\__|
                |_|
*/
/**************************************************************************************************************************/
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* Middle Observation(1 ) of table =  - Total Obs 2 17MAY2023:09:30:14                                                    */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/*  -- NUMERIC --                                                                                                         */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/*               TYPE           LENGTH                                                                                    */
/* DESC_CD         N8             100    KEY                                                                              */
/* ITEM_CD         N8             458                                                                                     */
/* ABC1            N8              15                                                                                     */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* LINE_NBR1       N8               1                                                                                     */
/* TYPE_CD1        N8               3                                                                                     */
/* VAL11           N8              50                                                                                     */
/* VAL21           N8               0                                                                                     */
/* VAL31           N8             100                                                                                     */
/* ABC2            N8              15                                                                                     */
/* LINE_NBR2       N8               2                                                                                     */
/* TYPE_CD2        N8               6                                                                                     */
/* VAL12           N8               0                                                                                     */
/* VAL22           N8             150                                                                                     */
/* VAL32           N8               0                                                                                     */
/* ABC3            N8              15                                                                                     */
/* LINE_NBR3       N8               3                                                                                     */
/* TYPE_CD3        N8               9                                                                                     */
/* VAL13           N8              50                                                                                     */
/* VAL23           N8             150                                                                                     */
/* VAL33           N8               0                                                                                     */
/* ABC4            N8               .                                                                                     */
/* LINE_NBR4       N8               .                                                                                     */
/* TYPE_CD4        N8               .                                                                                     */
/* VAL14           N8               .                                                                                     */
/* VAL24           N8               .                                                                                     */
/* VAL34           N8               .                                                                                     */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/**************************************************************************************************************************/

/*
/ | __      ___ __  ___
| | \ \ /\ / / `_ \/ __|
| |  \ V  V /| |_) \__ \
|_|   \_/\_/ | .__/|___/
             |_|
*/

proc datasets lib=sd1 nolist nodetails;delete want; run;quit;

%utl_submit_wps64x('
libname sd1 "d:/sd1";
options sasautos="c:/otowps";
%utl_transpose(data=sd1.have,by=desc_cd item_cd,var=abc line_nbr type_cd val1-val3,out=sd1.want);
proc print data=sd1.want;
run;quit;
');

/*___
|___ \   ___  __ _ ___
  __) | / __|/ _` / __|
 / __/  \__ \ (_| \__ \
|_____| |___/\__,_|___/

*/

proc datasets lib=sd1 nolist nodetails;delete want; run;quit;

%utl_transpose(data=sd1.have,by=desc_cd item_cd,var=abc line_nbr type_cd val1-val3,out=sd1.want);


/**************************************************************************************************************************/
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* The WPS System                                                                                                         */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* Middle Observation(1 ) of table =  - Total Obs 2 17MAY2023:09:40:32                                                    */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/*  -- NUMERIC --                                                                                                         */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/*               TYPE           LENGTH                                                                                    */
/* DESC_CD         N8             100    KEY                                                                              */
/* ITEM_CD         N8             458                                                                                     */
/* ABC1            N8              15                                                                                     */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* LINE_NBR1       N8               1                                                                                     */
/* TYPE_CD1        N8               3                                                                                     */
/* VAL11           N8              50                                                                                     */
/* VAL21           N8               0                                                                                     */
/* VAL31           N8             100                                                                                     */
/* ABC2            N8              15                                                                                     */
/* LINE_NBR2       N8               2                                                                                     */
/* TYPE_CD2        N8               6                                                                                     */
/* VAL12           N8               0                                                                                     */
/* VAL22           N8             150                                                                                     */
/* VAL32           N8               0                                                                                     */
/* ABC3            N8              15                                                                                     */
/* LINE_NBR3       N8               3                                                                                     */
/* TYPE_CD3        N8               9                                                                                     */
/* VAL13           N8              50                                                                                     */
/* VAL23           N8             150                                                                                     */
/* VAL33           N8               0                                                                                     */
/* ABC4            N8               .                                                                                     */
/* LINE_NBR4       N8               .                                                                                     */
/* TYPE_CD4        N8               .                                                                                     */
/* VAL14           N8               .                                                                                     */
/* VAL24           N8               .                                                                                     */
/* VAL34           N8               .                                                                                     */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/**************************************************************************************************************************/

/*              _
  ___ _ __   __| |
 / _ \ `_ \ / _` |
|  __/ | | | (_| |
 \___|_| |_|\__,_|

*/


/*        _       _           _                            _ _             _
 _ __ ___| | __ _| |_ ___  __| |  _ __ ___ _ __   ___  ___(_) |_ ___  _ __(_) ___  ___
| `__/ _ \ |/ _` | __/ _ \/ _` | | `__/ _ \ `_ \ / _ \/ __| | __/ _ \| `__| |/ _ \/ __|
| | |  __/ | (_| | ||  __/ (_| | | | |  __/ |_) | (_) \__ \ | || (_) | |  | |  __/\__ \
|_|  \___|_|\__,_|\__\___|\__,_| |_|  \___| .__/ \___/|___/_|\__\___/|_|  |_|\___||___/
                                          |_|

*/

see github
```